# quoting problem with mysql

Tags: bash, ubuntu, quoting, mysql

I'm running the following command and receiving an error related to quoting or something.

```
#!/bin/bash
test='my_table'
date='2020-10-31 00:00:00.000000'

mysql --user=halloween --password='ghost_123' --database='ghost_database' <<END
use ghost_datebase;
CREATE EVENT myevent    ON SCHEDULE AT \"$date"\ ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE  ENABLE DO  SELECT * FROM "$test";
END
```

I then receive the following error:

```
ERROR at line 2: Unknown command '\"'.
```

Comment: No need to escape the quotes, but the quotes themselves may be needed. Not around $test, though.

Answer (score 1):

The qouted string became a here document:

```
<<END
CREATE EVENT $name ON SCHEDULE
  AT Str_to_date('$date', '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f')
  ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO SELECT * FROM $test;
END
```

I have run the following with success on a MariaDB database:

```
export DATE='2020-10-28 14:00:00.000000'
export NAME=eventje
export TEST=test

mysql --password='xYzAbC'  --database=ghp <<END
DROP EVENT $NAME;
CREATE EVENT $NAME ON SCHEDULE
  AT Str_to_date('$DATE', '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f')
  ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO SELECT * FROM $TEST;
END
```

Comment: Hi @gerard-h-pille

Please let me run my tests

Comment: I ran tests and received an error related to quoting.

the error message repeated the "on completion....." portion of the command

Comment: Perhaps you could add your test and the full error message to your question?

Comment: ERROR at line 2: Unknown command '\"'.

Comment: look at my question update

Comment: Answer following your update.

Comment: Hello Gerald.

I received the following error..

please look at it on screenshot

https://snipboard.io/aGdQr4.jpg

https://snipboard.io/eagDJd.jpg

Comment: It looks as if there is a problem with the fact that there are multiple lines, or there really is a syntax error in your statement.  I will have to try this myself.  What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: No problem with multiple lines.  So there must be a problem with your variables or you didn't copy my example literally.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Double-quote the `END` label that identifies the start of the here-doc. Then use proper MySQL syntax inside the here-doc - don't escape quotes unless they would be escaped normally for MySQL

```
mysql --user='halloween' --password='ghost_123' --database='ghost_database' <<"END"
CREATE EVENT myevent ON SCHEDULE AT "$date" ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO SELECT * FROM "$test";
END
```

Note that I've not attempted to fix your SQL syntax. Me, I'm not entirely sure that double-quotes are correct for table names (or for strings even).

If you didn't have any variables to interpolate it would have been correct to single-quote the here-doc identifier. (The quoting is just the same as for a string.)

Comment: on this sample, IMO `$date` should be quoted (double or single) and `$test` might be.

Comment: I still received an error on this

Comment: "An" error?  Should we guess?

Comment: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near halloween at line 1
'

Comment: @IanArman no, _you_ have an error in your SQL syntax. Me, I'm not sure that MySQL should have table names quoted, nor that it uses double-quotes to quote strings. I just copied your syntax

Comment: You can' use a quoted here document here since they want both `$test` and `$date` to be expanded. In the SQL, the date needs to be double quoted (or single quoted, I never get it right) and the table name that `$test` expands to does not need to be quoted, so the escaped quotes around `$date` should loose their backslashes, and the quotes around `$test` should be dropped.

Comment: I added variations to the quotations: ("$date", '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f')

I'm still getting errors related to quotes

Comment: In standard SQL, strings of data need single quotes. Double-quotes quote table/column names. But MySQL spoiled it by accepting double-quotes for data too, which just confuses the issue. And then there's backticks and brackets. And SQLite that bends the rules trying to be compatible with all: https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: can someone test this and give me a correct answer?

Comment: Create some working SQL inside the MySQL environment. (I can't right now.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using the following script:

There is only a double quote around the $date variable

```````````````````
date='2020-10-31 00:00:00.000000'

#CREATE EVENT myevent ON SCHEDULE AT "$date" ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO SELECT * FROM '$test';
mysql --user=halloween --password='ghost_123' --database='ghost_database' <<END
use ghost_database;
CREATE EVENT myevent ON SCHEDULE AT "$date" ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO SELECT * FROM ghost_database;
END

``````````````````


This script can be run separately if needed using an input argument:
In this example below the input argument is 'ghost'.  It could technically lookup whatever variables or be passed the date variable in epoch and simply convert it.

`````````````````
while getopts i: option

do
case "${option}"
in
i) ghost=${OPTARG};;
esac
```````````````````